# Is there a scatter operation in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to perform the reverse operation to `gather` or `gather_nd`, basically distributing a tensor into specific indices of another tensor (and filling the remaining entries with 0)?

In particular, I would like to scatter columns of a matrix into specific columns of another matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an operator called [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#scatter_nd), which does exactly what you're looking for.